# Bug in Finnish date localization?

Tags: java, localization, locale, date-format, finnish

I'm trying to localize for Finland using this code:

```
Locale finLocale = new Locale("fi", "FI");
Date today = new Date(2017, 1, 1);
DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.LONG, finLocale);
String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(today);
System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

What I end up getting is "helmikuutata". I would expect "helmikuu" or "helmikuuta", but this just seems wrong.

Is this valid Finnish, or is there a bug in Java? My version is 1.8.0_31

Comment: I'm getting `1. helmikuuta 3917`.

Comment: As an aside, everyone should avoid the outdated classes `Date` and `DateFormat` and even more so the deprecated 3-arg `Date()` constructor. And when you are using Java 8, there are no excuses left. The Java 8 date and time API is much more programmer friendly and nice to work with, so do yourself the favour. It has been backported to Java 6 and 7 too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this was a bug in JDK (See [JDK-8074791](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8074791)),  wherein an extra `'ta'` was appended to the month name. This got fixed from `JDK 8u60` version onwards. So, if you upgrade to latest JDK versions like `JDK8u131`, you will get the correct output.

Answer (score 3):

I am convinced that [the answer by Pallavi Sonal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44816206/5772882) is correct. I have already upvoted it and you should probably accept it. I had wanted to keep the following a comment, but it deserves better formatting, so here goes.

## java.time

Since you are using Java 8 (and even if you didn’t), you will prefer the modern more programmer friendly API of java.time:

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.of(2017, Month.FEBRUARY, 1);
DateTimeFormatter dateFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.LONG)
            .withLocale(finLocale);
String formattedDate = today.format(dateFormat);
```

On my Java 1.8.0_131 it gives the expected

```
1. helmikuuta 2017
```

If someone reading this is using Java 6 or 7, please consider getting the [*ThreeTen Backport*](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) library so you can use the modern date and time API as shown.

Comment: Yes, that's much better. Thanks.